# Add business hours to Java DateTime

Tags: java, algorithm, date

For an issue tracking system I need to calculate the response time for a request. The timer for response time should only be running during business hours. What algorithm/library should I use for this task? (Sure thing, I know about Joda-Time or ObjectLab Kit, but couldn't find anything helping with my task. Am I missing something?)

Example:

- Business hours: 9am - 5pm (8 hours per day)
- Maximum response time: 16 hours

The method may look something like:

```
DateTime calculateResponseTime(DateTime issueReportedAt)
```

I'll give some possible inputs and results as example:

- Mon, 2011-09-19, 1:00pm  -> Wed, 2011-09-21, 1:00pm
- Mon, 2011-09-19, 6:05pm  -> Thu, 2011-09-22, 9:00am
- Fri, 2011-09-23, 2:00pm  -> Tue, 2011-09-27, 2:00pm

Comment: That'll be fun once you have people in another culture and timezone doing some parts of the support…

Comment: Right, but I'm dead sure that won't happen to this project. ;)

Comment: this is the answer without DateTime, in case anybody needs it http://stackoverflow.com/a/34944057/2296787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look on the [jBPM business calendar](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/userguide/businesscalendar.html).

Another [library](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/) allows you configure bank holidays but it doesn't have a notion of business hours.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to jBPM. That's right jBPM does support business hours. But wouldn't it be  overkill to include a complete workflow engine with all its complexity for this one task? As I said, I know ObjectLab Kit, which I don't see to be helpful with this objective.

Comment: I ended up coding it myself. Was just curious about a usable library for this.

Comment: Looking on the number of votes to your question I think you are not alone who are looking for such library.

Answer (score 2):

I think what Oleg was suggesting was taking a look at the way jBPM implements this functionality for inspiration for coding your own solution.  Below is my answer borrowing heavily from the source I found by doing a [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch#1V7zA37LF4Q/src/java.jbpm/org/jbpm/calendar/DayPart.java&q=org.jbpm.calendar.DayPart&type=cs).

It does not take into account holidays, but I will leave that as an exercise for you.  May I suggest using a [web service](http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx/GetHolidaysForYear?countryCode=UnitedStates&year=2012) to annually update a restricted date list?  Good luck!

```
    int fromHour = 9;
int fromMinute = 0;
int toHour = 17;
int toMinute = 0;
long maxResponseTime = 16;

Date calculateResponseTime(Date issueReportedAt, long responseHours) {

    Date end = null;

    Calendar responseTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    responseTime.setTime(issueReportedAt);

    int hourOfDay = responseTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int dayOfWeek = responseTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if (hourOfDay < fromHour) {
        responseTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, fromHour);

    }

    if (hourOfDay >= toHour || dayOfWeek == 1) {
        responseTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        responseTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromHour);
        responseTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, fromMinute);

    } else if (dayOfWeek == 7) {
        responseTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        responseTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromHour);
        responseTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, fromMinute);

    }

    int hour = responseTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = responseTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    long dateMilliseconds = ((hour * 60) + minute) * 60 * 1000;
    long dayPartEndMilleseconds = ((toHour * 60) + toMinute) * 60 * 1000;
    long millisecondsInThisDayPart = dayPartEndMilleseconds
            - dateMilliseconds;

    long durationMilliseconds = responseHours * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    if (durationMilliseconds < millisecondsInThisDayPart) {
        end = new Date(responseTime.getTimeInMillis()
                + durationMilliseconds);
    } else {
        long remainder = (durationMilliseconds - millisecondsInThisDayPart) / 60 / 60 / 1000;
        Date dayPartEndDate = new Date(responseTime.getTimeInMillis()
                + durationMilliseconds);

        responseTime.setTime(dayPartEndDate);

        end = calculateResponseTime(responseTime.getTime(), remainder);
    }

    return end;

}

@Test
public void testCalculateResponseTime() {

    Calendar issueReportedAt = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar expectedResponseTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    issueReportedAt.set(2011, 8, 19, 13, 0, 0);
    expectedResponseTime.set(2011, 8, 21, 13, 0, 0);

    assertTrue(expectedResponseTime.getTime().equals(
            calculateResponseTime(issueReportedAt.getTime(),
                    maxResponseTime)));

    issueReportedAt.set(2011, 8, 19, 18, 5, 0);
    expectedResponseTime.set(2011, 8, 22, 9, 0, 0);

    assertTrue(expectedResponseTime.getTime().equals(
            calculateResponseTime(issueReportedAt.getTime(),
                    maxResponseTime)));

    issueReportedAt.set(2011, 8, 23, 14, 0, 0);
    expectedResponseTime.set(2011, 8, 27, 14, 0, 0);

    assertTrue(expectedResponseTime.getTime().equals(
            calculateResponseTime(issueReportedAt.getTime(),
                    maxResponseTime)));

}
```

Comment: There is a bug in the normalization part of your code. If the issue is reported on a Friday 10:00 AM and the responseHours is 10, than in the next recursive call the issueReportedAt will be Friday 10 PM, witch will be normalized to Saturday 9:00 PM, witch is invalid as well. See my answer for the fixed normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra if case to the normalization part from Anils answer because if the issue is reported on a Friday 10:00 AM and the responseHours is 10, than in the next recursive call the issueReportedAt will be Friday 10 PM, witch will be normalized to Saturday 9:00 PM, witch is invalid as well.

```
if (hourOfDay >= WorkingHours.TO_HOUR && dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        responseTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
        responseTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, WorkingHours.FROM_HOUR);
        responseTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, WorkingHours.FROM_MINUTE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code does solve the this problem

```
public static Date addBusinessHours(Calendar startDate, int hours, int workingHourStart, int workingHourEnd){
    System.out.println("Entering: Date Time " + startDate.getTime() + " | Remaining Hours: "+ hours + " | Working hours ("+workingHourStart+"-"+workingHourEnd+")");

    if(hours == 0){
        return startDate.getTime();
    }
    int hourOfDay = startDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if(startDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE) > 0){
        hourOfDay = hourOfDay +1;
    }

    int dayOfWeek = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if(dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY){
        startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, workingHourStart);
        startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        addBusinessHours(startDate, hours, workingHourStart, workingHourEnd);
    }
    if(dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY){
        startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, workingHourStart);
        startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        addBusinessHours(startDate, hours, workingHourStart, workingHourEnd);
    }

    if(dayOfWeek != Calendar.SATURDAY && dayOfWeek != Calendar.SUNDAY){
        if(hourOfDay < workingHourStart){
            startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, workingHourStart);
            startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            hourOfDay = startDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            dayOfWeek = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            addBusinessHours(startDate, hours, workingHourStart, workingHourEnd);
        }
        else if(hourOfDay >= workingHourEnd){

            startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, workingHourStart);
            startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            hourOfDay = startDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            dayOfWeek = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            addBusinessHours(startDate, hours, workingHourStart, workingHourEnd);
        }

        else if(hourOfDay >= workingHourStart && hourOfDay < workingHourEnd){
            if(hours+hourOfDay <= workingHourEnd){
                startDate.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
                return startDate.getTime();
            }else{
                //System.out.println("¤¤" + startDate.getTime() );
                startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                //System.out.println("¤¤" + startDate.getTime() );
                startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, workingHourStart);
                startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                //System.out.println("¤¤" + startDate.getTime() );

                System.out.println("##"+hours+ "##"+ workingHourEnd + "##" + hourOfDay);
                int remaining_hours = hours - (workingHourEnd - hourOfDay);
                addBusinessHours(startDate, remaining_hours, workingHourStart, workingHourEnd);
            }
        }
    }

    return startDate.getTime();
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque I will surely check. Thanks much! :D