# Java code to check if event timestamp falls in weekdays and business hours from 9:30 AM to 4:00 PM

Tags: java, date, calendar, timestamp

What is the best way in Java to check if event timestamp falls in weekdays and business hours from 9:30 AM to 4:00 PM and name the variable like Event_Type = "business" or "non business" based on the comparison.

1) Time stamps are Unix Time stamps.

2) Time zone differences are not a concern as all event time stamps abelong to the same timezone (Chicago Central TimeZone).

3) Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday are business days. Remaining days are not. Within in these business days if timestamp falls between 9:30 AM to 4:00 PM then event_type varible is equal to "business" other wise it should be non business.

I am looking for the best way to do this efficiently for a large amount of data.

I am looking for something using java.util Calendar Object

Comment: Can you please show the code ? What are the specific problems you're facing ?

Comment: Needs more details: In what format do you have event timestamps? Are timezone differences of concern? Business days based on [what region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend#Around_the_world)?

Comment: Just Updated the question.

Comment: By the way, a similar question that may be of interest: [How to add Business hours to Date considering not adding weekends ? - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34943530/642706).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option

```
    Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar begin = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();

    begin.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
    begin.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 29);
    begin.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    end.set(Calendar.HOUR, 4);
    end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 01);
    end.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

    if (d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY || d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY
            || (d.after(begin) && d.before(end))) {
        System.out.println("YAY!");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick Reply. I am looking for something using Calendar Object

Comment: The solution took about 12 milliseconds to run.

Comment: Using the `Calendar` class is not recommended. It was always poorly deigned and cumbersome to work with and was already outdated when this answer was posted in 2016. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as shown in the other two answers.

Answer (score 4):

## Unix Time

The phrase "[Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)" does not have an exact meaning. Often people mean a count of seconds since the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), ignoring [Leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). Sometimes people mean another granularity, commonly milliseconds. In the old days a 32-bit integer was used, creating the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), nowadays often a 64-bit integer is used.

## Time zone

> Time zone differences are not a concern as all event time stamps abelong to the same timezone (Chicago Central TimeZone).

Time zone is always a concern! To determine a day-of-week we need a date. To determine a date we need a time zone. For any given moment the date (and time-of-day) varies around the world by time zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris is a new day but is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

Furthermore, the Unix-style timestamps you mentioned are commonly intended to represent a moment in UTC. So you need a time zone to adjust into Chicago time frame.

If you do not specify a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly silently applied. That means your results will vary as that default time zone varies. Changes to the host computer and OS may impact the default time zone, as can any code in any app within the JVM via a call to `TimeZone.setDefault` – even *during* runtime of your code. So never rely on the implicit default; always specify your desired/expected time zone.

`CST` and `Chicago Central Time` and [`Central Time Zone`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone) are not exactly time zones. True [time zones are named with a `continent/region` pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). These time zones contain a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) that can vary historically for the various regions.

## java.time

The Question and the accepted Answer both use troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those classes are now legacy, now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

## Get zoned date-time

First step, convert your count-of-seconds-from-epoch to an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = 1464645007L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( secondsSinceEpoch );
```

Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get an object with the [Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago) [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) and with the Chicago-area’s history of anomaly adjustments ([`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

## Predicate

Now we can move to the core of the question, asking if this particular moment happens to be land on a week-day and within business hours within the context of the Chicago-area time zone.

Java 8 and later includes a formal structure for asking a boolean question, for asking if an object meets some criteria: [`Predicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). This simple interface has a method [`test`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-) which we need to implement, where we define our criteria for a TRUE or a FALSE.

Below is the source code for an entire class implementing the `Predicate` interface with a `test` method that holds our business logic for testing day-of-week and time-of-day.

First using Java Generics, we declare that we are working with an object of `ZonedDateTime`.

Then we use the handy `DayOfWeek` enum to define what we mean by "week-day". An `EnumSet` is a handy way to collect a subset of the values defined in an enum, as where where we collect 5 of the 7 possible day-of-week values.

We define business hours as `LocalTime` values. Be careful about the `Local…` types as they purposely have no time zone info. But here in this code the use of `LocalTime` is fine, as we extract the local time from the `ZonedDateTime` within the context of a time zone we expect.

The approach of this class assumes we have a `ZonedDateTime` assigned a Chicago time zone. For defensive programming, we should verify that assumption. If we were passed an object for `Pacific/Auckland` time zone assigned, the rest of our code would be testing the day-of-week and time-of-day for New Zealand, which is certainly *not* the same time frame as Chicago. As a simple solution, we test the passed `ZonedDateTime` for a `ZoneId` whose name is `America/Chicago`. A more sophisticated alternative might be to require passing an `Instant`, or a superclass, and convert the passed data into a `ZonedDateTime` with Chicago `ZoneId`. That is left as an exercise to the reader.

Another alternate design you could pursue is to pass 4 arguments to a constructor rather than hard-code the definition of weekdays, start time, stop time, and time zone as we do here in four `private static final` objects.

The rest of the code is straightforward `if()` testing. The start and stop times are compared using the Half-Open approach commonly used with date-time work. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. You use this Half-Open approach intuitively when you say “Lunch break is noon to 1 PM”.

We also add a `toString` method to verify the class’s definitions of week-day, business hours, and time zone.

```
package com.example.javatimestuff;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

/**
 *
 * © 2016 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used at your own risk according
 * to the terms of the ISC License: https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC
 *
 * @author Basil Bourque.
 */
public class isDuringBusinessHoursPredicate implements Predicate<ZonedDateTime> {

    private static final EnumSet<DayOfWeek> WEEKDAYS = EnumSet.of ( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY , DayOfWeek.FRIDAY );
    private static final LocalTime START = LocalTime.of ( 9 , 30 );
    private static final LocalTime STOP = LocalTime.of ( 16 , 0 );
    private static final ZoneId ZONEID_AMERICA_CHICAGO = ZoneId.of ( "America/Chicago" );

    // Method tests to see if the passed date-time is on a Chicago week-day and within business hours.
    @Override
    public boolean test ( ZonedDateTime zdt ) {
        // Verify argument.
        boolean expectedTimeZone = zdt.getZone ().equals ( ZONEID_AMERICA_CHICAGO );
        if (  ! expectedTimeZone ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "Expected argument to have a time zone: " + ZONEID_AMERICA_CHICAGO );
        }
        // Determine the day-of-week to see if it with our definition of a week-day.
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = zdt.getDayOfWeek ();
        boolean isWeekday = WEEKDAYS.contains ( dayOfWeek );
        // If a week-day, determine if the time-of-day is within our definition of business hours. Half-open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
        if ( isWeekday ) {
            LocalTime localTime = zdt.toLocalTime ();
            boolean withinBusinessHours = (  ! localTime.isBefore ( START ) && localTime.isBefore ( STOP ) );
            return withinBusinessHours;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "isDuringBusinessHours{ " + "weekdays=" + WEEKDAYS.toString () + " | start=" + START + " | stop=" + STOP + " | timeZone: " + ZONEID_AMERICA_CHICAGO + " }";
    }

}
```

Now back to our code we began at the top of this Answer, to use an instance of our new `isDuringBusinessHoursPredicate` class.

```
Predicate p = new isDuringBusinessHoursPredicate ();
boolean isBiz = p.test ( zdt );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt + " | isBizTime: " + isBiz + " | p: " + p );
```

> zdt: 2016-05-30T16:50:07-05:00[America/Chicago] | isBizTime: false | p: isDuringBusinessHours{ weekdays=[MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY] | start=09:30 | stop=16:00 | timeZone: America/Chicago }

## Why `Predicate`?

Why bother to move our criteria logic into a class implementing [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html)? If you ever need that logic in more than one place, you now have a simple way to re-use that logic. Also, that interface happens to be a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) (an interface requiring only a single method) which can then be used with Java Streams (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) and [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)) and [Lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for some very powerful code with very short (simple?) syntax.

Comment: Thank you, Basil! Very well working solution and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is precisely the solution you need and no BS.

```
ZonedDateTime localDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime nowInNewYork= ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = localDateTime.getDayOfWeek();
    if(dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY){
        System.out.println("NOT Within Working Hours);   
    }  else if(nowInNewYork.getHour() < 9 
                    || (nowInNewYork.getHour() == 9 && nowInNewYork.getMinute() <30) 
                    || (nowInNewYork.getHour() > 15)){
        System.out.println("NOT Within Working Hours);  
    } else {
        System.out.println("Within Working Hours);     
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the use of java.time, the modern java date and time API that is precisely recommended. I am not sure why you are using one time zone for the day of week and another for the time of day, and I think that it may lead to an inconsistent result in corner cases. Also I think that the time comparison could be clearer if you convert t `LocalTime` and compare to `LocalTime` objects representing the start and end of business hours.

Comment: Please explain how you code helps answer the question and do not include unnecessary comments in the answer.